# Selenium Python Execute JavaScript click link i get an error. I think my syntax is wrong

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a link on our webpage.  The page is built from GWT.
I am using the JavaScript execute in Selenium Python.

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.gElementById('tab_administration').click()")
```

I get the following error when i run my code:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: JavaScript error
```

My code snippet is:

```
     def click_administration(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        #self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tab_administration').click()
        self.driver.execute_script("document.gElementById('tab_administration').click()")
        #wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        #element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tab_administration')))
        #element.click()
        return AdministrationPage(self.driver)
```

Is my JavaScript call syntax incorrect?  Why is it failing?

In Firefox dev tools it works.  From the console window i enter this line of code:

```
document.gElementById('tab_administration').click()";
```

I am trying driver.execute_script because when i try WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10) i get a TimeOut Exception.

Some help appreciated.  Thanks.

Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", yourElement);
```

Comment: That's brilliant, it works.  The admin tab was clicked.  Thanks.

Comment: This is the code i used.  admin_tab = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tab_administration')
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", admin_tab)